# Managing user profiles with SimpleMembership/Sql Server CE, MongoDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I chose to use `mongodb` as a storage for *domain-centric data*.
I was searching for `official mongodb providers` to integrate them into `ASP.NET MVC` project to keep a single application database. There are no official providers and available ones don't look mature/stable. So I decided to use simple membership as it is.

How to get rid of `Entity Framework`-specific code, if possible, from the `AccountController`?

How would you manage user profiles having both `SimpleMembership UserProfile` and `MongoDB` `User`?

**Example**

In a separate assembly `[project-name].domain` there are two classes:

```
public class Event {
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Events> AssociatedEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Will this be a solution if I add an `UserProfileId` to `User`?

```
public class User {
    public Int32 UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Events> AssociatedEvents { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you need AspNet.Identity implementation for MongoDB for replacing default AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework usage in standart AccountController in ASP.NET MVC 5? If yes - [maybe this helps you](https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity) - fully implemented MongoDB.AspNet.Identity.

Comment: Do you know if this will work with MVC4?  Going to try either way, but wanted to know if this is MVC5 specific and save myself some pain if so...

Comment: Microsoft Owin distributes over NuGet, so it looks like , that you may add it to your MVC4 project and use Owin identity instead of old Forms/Membership providers model.

Comment: Went the MVC5 route. Starting a new project... might as well start with the latest/greatest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

you have to use connectionString from an appSetting.

You will need to download the above fork, build & change your existing dll reference to use the new dll.

Then...

Use your config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="MONGOLAB_URL" value="mongodb://localhost/ASPNETDB"/>    
</appSettings>
```

... the above value will get replaced by appharbor/mongolab (and if you have other parts of the app that work, then this is correct)

```
<providers>
   <clear />
   <add name="MongoDBMembershipProvider" type="MongoDB.Web.Providers.MongoDBMembershipProvider" 
    applicationName="/"  appSettingsConnectionStringKey="MONGOLAB_URL" collection="Users"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
</providers>
```

So in the above config, it has the appSettingsConnectionStringKey parameter. The code within the customised provider, reads the appSettingsConnectionStringKey value 'MONGOLAB_URL' and then uses that to read the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MONGOLAB_URL"] and it obviously, MUST match the appsetting Key name above.

[1]: https://github.com/osuritz

[2]: https://github.com/osuritz/MongoDB.Web/commit/b1e9534023ca8cb2e74eb1adbdcb1cd7dd693efa