# Sample MongoDB Membership in MVC5

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-5

Where I can find a simple solution of MongoDB Membership in ASP.NET MVC5 as an example? Having troubles with applying this [Managing user profiles with SimpleMembership/Sql Server CE, MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489123/managing-user-profiles-with-simplemembership-sql-server-ce-mongodb) I asked some questions but my messages were deleted, I don't know why. So I have to create new topic to get to know how to inplement Identity database right.

Comment: Your questions will have been deleted because you asked them on an old question instead of creating a new one. Your question will get more attention this way. Have you written any code?

Comment: Asking for link/tutorials/code examples isn't a good fit for StackOverflow, and those questions are generally closed. Instead, post some code that you're having trouble with for example, and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Ok, how can I upload archive with solution inside? Problem is that I don't know exactly which file exactly is wrong. That's why I can ask general question only but not unfortunatly specific. I suspect that instruction is not quite full for novices in ASP.NET and not all steps are pointed.

Comment: This is link to the solution http://yadi.sk/d/SivvJJizDjjpW. Please could you inspect a code?